# Sitecore 9.3 installation security error

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework

Has anyone faces this error while installing sitecore using the GUI interface?

```
Security error.
Security error.
Security error.
Security error.
                      ************************************
                           Sitecore Install Framework
                                 Version - 2.2.0
                      ************************************


WorkingDirectory       : C:\Projects\jss-app
WhatIf                 : False
Verbose                : SilentlyContinue
Configuration          : C:\Users\username\Downloads\Sitecore_9.3.0_rev._003498_(Setup_XP0_Developer_Workstation_
                         rev.1.1.1-r4)\Prerequisites.json
Debug                  : SilentlyContinue
AutoRegisterExtensions : False
WarningAction          : Continue
ErrorAction            : Stop
InformationAction      : Continue





[-- DownloadVisualC++2015x86 [Skipped] : DownloadFile ------------------------]

[--------- InstallC++2015x86 [Skipped] : StartProcess ------------------------]

[-- DownloadVisualC++2015x64 [Skipped] : DownloadFile ------------------------]

[--------- InstallC++2015x64 [Skipped] : StartProcess ------------------------]

[----------- SQLServerModule [Skipped] : InstallModule -----------------------]

[--------------------- WindowsFeatures : EnableWindowsOptionalFeature --------]

[ DownloadWebPlatformInstaller [Skipped] : DownloadFile ------------------------]

[ InstallWebPlatformInstaller [Skipped] : StartProcess ------------------------]
Unable to parse [variable('WebDeploy.Version.Compare')] - Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to parse [InvokeExpression(Command:variable('WebDeploy.Version.Command'))] - Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to parse [concat('[system.version]"',variable('WebDeploy.Null.Version'),'" -ge [system.version]"',variable('WebDeploy.Minimum.Version'),'"')] - Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to parse [if(variable('WebDeploy.Version'),variable('WebDeploy.Version'),'0.0')] - Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to parse [SelectObject(InputObject:variable('WebDeploy.Package'),ExpandProperty:'Version')] - Exception calling "InvokeWithContext" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Property "Version" cannot be found."""""
[TIME] 00:00:11
Unable to parse [variable('WebDeploy.Version.Compare')] - Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to parse [InvokeExpression(Command:variable('WebDeploy.Version.Command'))] - Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to parse [concat('[system.version]"',variable('WebDeploy.Null.Version'),'" -ge [system.version]"',variable('WebDeploy.Minimum.Version'),'"')] - Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to parse [if(variable('WebDeploy.Version'),variable('WebDeploy.Version'),'0.0')] - Exception calling "Evaluate" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Unable to parse [SelectObject(InputObject:variable('WebDeploy.Package'),ExpandProperty:'Version')] - Exception calling "InvokeWithContext" with "2" argument(s): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Property "Version" cannot be found."""""
```

I'm running the sitecore installation exe as an admin user.

Answer (score 0):

There are issue related to Webdeploy download from config prerequisites.json, will suggest to download manually Webdeploy 3.6 version https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43717
And then try again with exe.

Comment: Thank you Pradeep. I did try this but I'm still seeing the same error. Any idea why the initial Security Errors would be showing up? I'm running the installer with admin privileges.

Comment: Please ensure you have full administrator rights from IT team.

Answer (score 0):

### Couple of things to try:

- **If you have never installed Sitecore 9 before, you will probably want to execute**

> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted

- **Enable Contained Database Authentication if not yet**: In order to enable contained databases on SQL Server, run this SQL script through SQL Server Management Studio:

> EXEC sp_configure ‘contained’, 1;
> RECONFIGURE;

- Make sure all pre-requisites are installed properly.
- **Check you've local admin rights to the machine** and give below access to *wwwroot* folder

> a. Network Service -> Full Access
> b. IIS_IUSERS -> Full Access
> c. LOCAL SERVICE -> Full access

Refer to this post for more details: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sitecore-93-local-installation-raman-gupta/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have only one version of WebDeploy installed on your machine. If you have multiple versions installed, Sitecore installation script would crash.